# AWS step functions 1year limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

we have human tasks which will be open for more than 3 years. The AWS step function human task has limit of 1year so I timing out the task in 364days and catching the timeout exception and re-running it again for another 364days.

Now the overall execution time of step function will cross more than a year will it cause problem?

We can have more than 25,000 of these open executions waiting for human approval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the execution times out and you start a new execution then I can't think of any problem. There is a default of 1,000,000 open executions by default, so you should be fine with the 25,000 you mentioned.

Comment: No overall execution is remained open, it's just the timeout set for waitforcallback task to 364days and catching it to re-run the task again, but now execution is opened for more than 1year will it cause problem?

Comment: As per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits-overview.html#service-limits-state-machine-executions, the maximum execution time for a state machine is 1 year, so you will need to start a new execution